# Are clopen sets of rational sequences $F_{\sigma\delta}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology, rational-numbers

I am studying properties of clopen subsets of $\mathbb{Q}^{\omega}$ (subsets of the space of all rational sequences, endowed with the product topology) and for verifying some properties, I need the clopen subsets to be $F_{\sigma\delta}$ (and nowhere $G_{\delta\sigma}$).

I have only basic understanding of this property and definitions ([**$F_{\sigma\delta}$**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F%CF%83_set) is defined as the intersection of countably many unions of countable closed sets, [**$G_{\delta\sigma}$**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%CE%B4_set) is kind of a dual notion).

**The question**: Could you please help me prove that any clopen subset of $\mathbb{Q}^{\omega}$ is $F_{\sigma\delta}$ and nowhere $G_{\delta\sigma}$?

**My thoughts** are to first check the $F_{\sigma}$ (= being union of countable closed sets) and then check **$F_{\sigma\delta}$**.

The $F_{\sigma}$ seems trivial to me - any clopen set of rational sequences should be "composed" from countable closed sets, since we are in a rational world, right?

With the second part (checking this forms countable intersection to get $F_{\sigma\delta}$) seems much harder to me.

Any thoughts?

Comment: An $F_{\sigma\delta}$ set can be written as $\bigcap_{n \in \Bbb N}\bigcup_{m \in N_n} F_m$ where each $N_n$ is a countable set and all $F_m, m \in N_n, n \in \Bbb N$ are closed.

Comment: There are also separable metrisable spaces $X$ that are called absolutely of some Borel class: they then have that class in $Y$ for whatever Polish $Y$ $X$ is embedded in. An absolutely closed space is compact. An absolute $G_\delta$ is a completely metrisable space. An absolute $F_\sigma$ is $\sigma$-compact. This is classic stuff from the 1920's.

Comment: so trivially a clopen set is $F_{\sigma\delta}$ in $\Bbb Q^\omega$ but the question is whether that is absolutely the case.

Comment: See [this paper](https://dml.cz/bitstream/handle/10338.dmlcz/127398/CzechMathJ_48-1998-1_5.pdf) e.g.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma And does being $F_{\sigma \delta}$ imply being nowhere $G_{ \delta \sigma}$ in the case of $\mathbb{Q}^{\omega}$? If it is something like a complement, but all clopen subsets of $\mathbb{Q}^{\omega}$ are $F_{\sigma \delta}$, I think they have to be nowhere $G_{\delta \sigma}$ then.